# Nested Maven Multi Module benefits over simple dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

This question is extension of [this SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559041/maven-multi-module-benefits-over-simple-dependency) but in my case I not only have modules but they are nested, is there any benefit of nested modules. For example if you have structure like

`parent
   |-> child1
         | - > child2
                |-> child3
                      |-> child4
                           |-> child5`

Would you rather have

`parent
  |-> child1
  |-> child2
  |-> child3
  |-> child4
  |-> child5`

What are the advantage and disadvantage of both approach.

Comment: The nested structure makes only sense if you have modules which have an appropriate architecture..otherwise it does not make sense...For example this one has two level structure https://github.com/khmarbaise/supose which makes sense base on the architecture...I would never flatten that

Comment: @khmarbaise - thank, I would never flatten out 2 levels but 5 level nesting is just too much I think

Comment: That depends on the project and it's architecture but I would reconsider this number of levels..

Answer (score 1):

Multi module project structure is good for, when you want to execute a maven command for multiple sub projects and dont have to care about order of build.(which one is dependent to other is handled automatically)For example: installing all the modules or generating javadocs for all the modules.

Parent structure is good for; inheriting dependency, plugin etc.. configuration from chain of parents. In the example you provided child5 will have dependency for every dependency it's chain of parents have defined.(in their `<dependencies>` tag) But as a good thing child5 wont have to  specify a version for dependency which its chain of parents defined in the `<dependencyManagement>` tag.

If your child1-child5 is reponsible for different business logic(as a result will have very wide range of dependencies), multi module should be used.

One of the most popular maven project spring-boot have both of these concepts. I suggest you check it out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project

Comment: thanks for answer, I am fine with two level nesting but 5 level nesting is just too much.